# Is there a way to make PyDub's overlay feature quicker?

Tags: pydub

I have been working on an audio program that uses an audio object from "AudioSegment.from_wav," and I have been using that to overlay it with other audio, but it takes too much time even with 20~ WAV files. Any ideas?

Already tried to fix problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.